# Colors bizarre results with right to left text

Tags: xetex, color, right-to-left, bidi, dvipdfmx

I have this example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

{\color{red} text from  left to right  text from  left to right   \par
text from  left to right  text from  left to right }

\hrulefill

\setRTL

\color{red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left
\par  text from  right to left text from  right to left \normalcolor

\hrulefill

{\color{red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left \par
 text from  right to left  text from  right to left}

\hrulefill

{before \color{red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left \par
 text from  right to left  text from  right to left}

\end{document}
```

With this result
[image]

Color of text in ltr (left to right) is fine, but in rtl effects of `\color` is confusing, also the text before `\color` is colored! look like the command is applied from the beginning to the end of the paragraph without regard of command position.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\setRTL

{\leavevmode\color{red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left \par
text from  right to left}  text from  right to left  \par 
text from  right to left  text from  right to left 

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 29/06/2018**

With `\addfontfeature{Color=red}` (command from `fontspec` package)  the problem can be solved like that

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\setRTL

before {\addfontfeature{Color=red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left \par
text from  right to left}  text from  right to left  \par 
text from  right to left  text from  right to left 

\end{document}
```

[image]

My aim is to find a method directly  with `xcolor` ( or `color`) package without reliance on package `fontspec`.

Comment: use `\textcolor{red}{....}` or `\leavevmode\color{red}.....`  so the colour change is inside the paragraph (there are multiple issues with using `\color` in vertical mode which are not really solvable without changing the underlying tex mechanisms.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a workaround (trick) to solve this (obtain colored text inside group without losing rtl direction of text )

Comment: doesn't  the suggestion in my first comment work?

Comment: The text  before `\color` command is also colored, I need onlly text inside braces to be colored.

Comment: yes as I said, replace `{\color{red} zzz}` by `\textolor{red}{zzz}` or `{\leavevmode\color{red} zzz}`  the color is limited to the  `{}` in all three cases.

Comment: I need to use `\color` command not `\textcolor`

Comment: and `{\leavevmode\color{red} xxx }` ?

Comment: Suitable in the case of a single paragraph, for  more than a paragraph problem of text direction appear.

Comment: really? if the colour starts and ends in horizontal mode I'd expect it to work, and of course your example above only has one paragraph...

Comment: I’m confused: You are using the `\setmainfont` command from the `fontspec` package, so `fontspec` must be loaded already. Why not just use the `fontspec` solution?

Comment: Why do you want an `xcolor` solution when you are committed to loading `fontspec` anyway? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I need to patch a class for right to left  version, this class use command `\color` profusely.

Comment: This error seems related to line breaks in RTL. If you use brackets only within a single line it should work as expected.

Comment: @SalimBou \addfontfeature{Color=red} not change color of math mode.

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions, but none of them is nice except the one solution you suggest on your own using `fontspec`:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\parindent=0pt

\newcommand{\parnew}[1][red]{\par\color{#1}}

\begin{document}

{\color{red} text from  left to right  text from  left to right   \par
text from  left to right  text from  left to right }

\hrulefill

\setRTL

{\color{red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left
{\parnew  text from  right to left text from  right to left} \normalcolor

}
\hrulefill

\newcommand{\mycolour}{blue}

{\color{\mycolour}{ text from  right to left  text from  right to left \parnew[\mycolour]
 text from  right to left  text from  right to left}

}
\hrulefill

before {\color{red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left} {\parnew
 text from  right to left  text from  right to left

}
\hrulefill

before \textcolor{red}{ text from  right to left  text from  right to left }\par
\textcolor{red}{text from  right to left  text from  right to left}

\hrulefill

\textcolor{black}{before}   {\color{red}text from  right to left  text from  right to left 

text from  right to left \textcolor{black}{text from  right to left}

}
\hrulefill

before {\addfontfeature{Color=red} text from  right to left  text from  right to left \par
    text from  right to left}  text from  right to left  \par 
text from  right to left  text from  right to left

\hrulefill


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP explained in his/her comment that an `xcolor` based solution was needed to patch a class. @mojtababaghban also pointed out `\addfontfeature{Color=red}` doesn’t change math mode color properly.

Comment: @RuixiZhang: I read the comment about `\addfontfeature{Color=red}`. Since it was reported by @mojtababaghban  and not the Autor, I thought it might not be a problem.
You just need to define new enviromnets such as \begin{myequation}[mycolor]...\end{myequation} or macros as {\myMathmode[mycolor]{...}}.