# Change color method used with beamer

Tags: beamer, macros, color

We have many issues when using `xcolor` with right to left text (pdflatex and xelatex)
[Colors bizarre results with right to left text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438323/colors-bizarre-results-with-right-to-left-text)

The answer suggest to use the command from `fontspec` package

```
{\addfontfeature{Color=red} colored text here }
```

I thought if it is  possible to change the definition of  command `\color` to be the same  as  `Color` from fontpec we can solve those issues even partially

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri} 
\usefonttheme{serif}


% redefine \color{#1} to be the same as \addfontfeature{Color=#1}  

\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\begin{document}
\raggedleft

\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
\item
text from right to left \alert{text from right to left text from right to left 
text from right to left} out
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}


\renewcommand{\alert}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Color=red}#1}}

\begin{frame}{title}

\begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
\item
text from right to left \alert{text from right to left text from right to left 
text from right to left} out
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is really not a good idea. `\addfontfeature` affects *only* fonts, not rules, not drawings like tikz. So in presentations you would e.g. loose all the frame colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
{\color{red}
some text in red
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\tikz\draw[<->,red](0,0)--++(1,1);
}
\def\color#1{\addfontfeature{Color=#1}}
\color{red}
some text in red
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\tikz\draw[<->,red](0,0)--++(1,1);
\end{document}
```

[image]