# Create an adapted \color macro for RTL mode (xelatex)

Tags: macros, color, right-to-left

This is a complement to these questions:

- [Colors bizarre results with right to left text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438323/colors-bizarre-results-with-right-to-left-text)
- [Change color method used with beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472744/change-color-method-used-with-beamer/472749#472749)

My aim is to create a macro like `\color` which can be used in RTL mode (right to left) and in all  circumstances  to color text and drawing stuff without issues:

Here my attempt (which use fontspec `Color` key to color text and normal `\color` to color rules and drawings but this need to patch every drawing stuff like `\rule`, `tikzpicture`,... )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Amiri}

\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\makeatletter
% patch \rule commmand
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\ifrtlcolor\textcolor{rtlcolor}{\old@rule[#1]{#2} 
 {#3}}\else\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}\fi}
\makeatother

\def\rtlcolor#1{%
\rtlcolortrue
\colorlet{rtlcolor}{#1}
\addfontfeature{Color=#1}
 }

\begin{document}

Right to left text {\rtlcolor{red} RED TEXT \rule{5pt}{5pt} right to left text  
right to left text right to left text right to left text right to left text } out of group 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is switching to luatex not an option for you? You are now fighting since weeks with the insufficient rtf model of xelatex.

Comment: Most of rtl writers use xelatex rather then lualatex because of the great support from `bidi` package

Comment: That's now. But seeing the lack of development  in xetex/bidi/polyglossia compared to the changes in bidi/babel and the luatex engine I would say it would make more sense to spent your time to improve luatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustration:

With `luacolor` package, colours are OK:

[image: luacolor example]

Code for specific letter range is from: [How to color specific characters in an Arabic string without losing connection?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597798/how-to-color-specific-characters-in-an-arabic-string-without-losing-connection)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% for (some) names
\usepackage{luacolor}

\newcounter{pft}

%\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
 
\setmainfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Noto Naskh Arabic}%{Amiri}





\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\pft#1-#2;{\edef\lower@pft{\the\numexpr#1-1}\edef\upper@pft{\the\numexpr#2+1}}%
\def\ColorRgChar#1#2{\pft#1;%
\setcounter{pft}{0}%
\@tfor\next:=#2\do{\stepcounter{pft}%
\ifnum\value{pft}>\lower@pft
 \ifnum\value{pft}<\upper@pft
  \textcolor{red}{\next}%
 \else
  \next
 \fi
\else
 \next
\fi
}}%
\makeatother

\Huge

\selectlanguage{arabic}
 \ColorRgChar{11-13}{المجموعة الشمسية}  

\par\selectlanguage{english} blue
\color{blue}\selectlanguage{arabic}\par
المجموعة الشمسية
\par\selectlanguage{english} brown\color{brown}\selectlanguage{arabic}\par
المجموعة الشمسية
\par\selectlanguage{english} violet\color{violet}\selectlanguage{arabic}\par
المجموعة 
\par\selectlanguage{english} green\color{green}\selectlanguage{arabic}\par
الشمسية


\end{document}
```