# How to color specific characters in an Arabic string without losing connection?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

Coloring Arabic letters without losing connection. I should get :
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{pft}

\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}
 
\setmainfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\pft#1-#2;{\edef\lower@pft{\the\numexpr#1-1}\edef\upper@pft{\the\numexpr#2+1}}%
\def\ColorRgChar#1#2{\pft#1;%
\setcounter{pft}{0}%
\@tfor\next:=#2\do{\stepcounter{pft}%
\ifnum\value{pft}>\lower@pft
 \ifnum\value{pft}<\upper@pft
  \textcolor{red}{\next}%
 \else
  \next
 \fi
\else
 \next
\fi
}}%
\makeatother
\Huge
\ColorRgChar{2-5}{Examination}

 \ColorRgChar{3-4}{كِثَبهَا}  

\end{document}
```

This gives
[image]

But I need :
[image]

Comment: The easy way would be to switch to LuaTeX and use `luacolor`. Then it should just work. If you want to sty with XeTeX you can try adding ZWNJ (U+200C) before and after `\next`, but it strongly depends on the context and the font if this works.

Comment: @ MarcelKrüger I have complied it with  LuaTeX and used luacolor, but the still remains the same problem.

Comment: you must select arabic with `\selectlanguage{arabic}`, without it the script is not activated.