# Coloring Arab Al-Quran

Tags: arabic

How can I change the color of Arab word endings without losing the connections? It's just ugly and loses readability. I'm using Texmaker and MiKTeX
Font KFGQPC HAFS Uthmanic Script
[image: Like this]

Comment: I wonder how you made it colored in the first place.

Comment: texmaker and miktex have no effect here, but are you using xelatex or lualalatex (and would you consider answers for either)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597798/how-to-color-specific-characters-in-an-arabic-string-without-losing-connection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe related, depending on what the specific problem actually is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529577/apply-command-on-range-of-characters-of-a-word

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473304/create-an-adapted-color-macro-for-rtl-mode-xelatex/646456#646456

Comment: thank you very much, i will try it

Comment: Related
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528341/emphasizing-arabic-text-characters

Comment: i made it in word and colored it in Photoshop