# RTL Coloring Mid-Line spreads to the entire and preceding line of output

Tags: color, overleaf, hebrew, right-to-left, bidi

I'm writing in Hebrew script on Overleaf using XeLaTeX and need to color different languages differently. The text יתברך ויתרומם should be colored in dark blue, but this is the result:[image]

I'm using `bidi` to do the RTL script and `xcolor` to color the text. The source for the pdf is as follows (it may be slightly off due to the RTL nature of the text):

```
\hbow\ מוֹדִֿים אֲנַֽחְנוּ לָךְֿ שָׁאַתָּה הוּא ה׳ אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבֿוֹתֵֽֿינוּ
לְעוֹלָם וָעֶדֿ צוּר חַיֵּֽינוּ מָגֵֿן יִשְׁעֵֽנוּ אַתָּה הוּא לְדֿוֹר וָדֿוֹר נֽוֹדֶֿה לְּךָֿ
וּנְסַפֵּר תְּהִלָּתֶֽֿךָֿ עַל־חַיֵּֽינוּ הַמְּסוּרִים בְּיָדֶֽֿךָֿ וְעַל נִשְׁמוֹתֵֽֿינוּ הַפְּקוּדֿוֹתֿ
לָךְֿ וְעַל נִסֶּֽיךָֿ שֶׁבְּכׇֿל־יוֹם עִמָּֽנוּ וְעַל נִפְֿלְאוֹתֶֽֿיךָֿ וְטוֹבֿוֹתֶֽֿיךָֿ שֶׁבְּכׇֿל־עֵתֿ
עֶֽרֶבֿ וָבֹֽֿקֶר וְצׇהֳרָֽיִם הַטּוֹבֿ כִּי לֹא כָֿלוּ רַחֲמֶֽיךָֿ וְהַמְרַחֵם כִּי לֹא תַֽֿמּוּ
חֲסָדֶֽֿיךָֿ מֵעוֹלָם קִוִּֽינוּ לָךְֿ׃ וְעַל־כֻּלָּם \aramaictext{יִתְֿבָּרַךְֿ וְיִתְֿרוֹמַם}
שִׁמְךָֿ מַלְכֵּֽנוּ תָּמִידֿ לְעוֹלָם וָעֶדֿ׃ וְכֹֿל הַחַיִּים יוֹדֽֿוּךָֿ סֶּֽלָה וִיהַלְ֒לוּ אֶתֿ־שִׁמְךָֿ
בֶּאֱמֶתֿ הָאֵ׳ יְשׁוּעָתֵֽֿנוּ וְעֶזְרָתֵֽֿנוּ סֶֽלָה׃ \hbow בָּרוּךְֿ אַתָּה ה׳ הַטּוֹבֿ שִׁמְךָֿ
וּלְךָֿ נָאֶה לְהוֹדֿוֹתֿ׃
```

And the source for `\aramaictext` is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\aramaictext}[1]{\textcolor{aramaic}{#1}}
```

I've tried using explicitly defining a regular font color as black and switching afterwards, but that also doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: I switched to LuaLaTex and `luabidi` (I couldn't get `babel` to work) and while the color issue is fixed I'm running into a new problem where the vowels aren't kerning correctly. The font I'm using is SBL BibLit; this doesn't happen in XeLaTex so idk why it's happening here. Here's the full page:
[image]

Comment: use lualatex and luacolor. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473304/create-an-adapted-color-macro-for-rtl-mode-xelatex

Answer (score 2):

Color is somewhat problematic and tricky  in XeTeX, so, as suggested by @UlrikeFischer in the comment above, consider switching to LuaTeX.

As one of the requirements is that you “need to color different **languages** differently”, here is an option based on this idea, with a new language in `babel`. Actually, `babel` provides some minimal locale files for Aramaic, but for the Imperial Aramaic, Palmyrene and Nabataean scripts, so I just create a new language based on the Hebrew locale (`he`). You don’t provide a MWE (even the image is incomplete), so it’s just a guess.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, hebrew, provide=*]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he]{aramaic}
% The global font:
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
% Declare a colorized font for aramaic:
\babelfont[aramaic]{rm}[Color=0033CC]{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\hsize5cm
\centering

מוֹדִֿים אֲנַֽחְנוּ לָךְֿ שָׁאַתָּה הוּא ה׳ אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבֿוֹתֵֽֿינוּ
לְעוֹלָם וָעֶדֿ צוּר חַיֵּֽינוּ מָגֵֿן יִשְׁעֵֽנוּ אַתָּה הוּא לְדֿוֹר וָדֿוֹר נֽוֹדֶֿה לְּךָֿ
וּנְסַפֵּר תְּהִלָּתֶֽֿךָֿ עַל־חַיֵּֽינוּ הַמְּסוּרִים בְּיָדֶֽֿךָֿ וְעַל נִשְׁמוֹתֵֽֿינוּ הַפְּקוּדֿוֹתֿ
לָךְֿ וְעַל נִסֶּֽיךָֿ שֶׁבְּכׇֿל־יוֹם עִמָּֽנוּ וְעַל נִפְֿלְאוֹתֶֽֿיךָֿ וְטוֹבֿוֹתֶֽֿיךָֿ שֶׁבְּכׇֿל־עֵתֿ
עֶֽרֶבֿ וָבֹֽֿקֶר וְצׇהֳרָֽיִם הַטּוֹבֿ כִּי לֹא כָֿלוּ רַחֲמֶֽיךָֿ וְהַמְרַחֵם כִּי לֹא תַֽֿמּוּ
חֲסָדֶֽֿיךָֿ מֵעוֹלָם קִוִּֽינוּ לָךְֿ׃ וְעַל־כֻּלָּם
\foreignlanguage{aramaic}{יִתְֿבָּרַךְֿ וְיִתְֿרוֹמַם}
שִׁמְךָֿ מַלְכֵּֽנוּ תָּמִידֿ לְעוֹלָם וָעֶדֿ׃ וְכֹֿל הַחַיִּים יוֹדֽֿוּךָֿ סֶּֽלָה וִיהַלְ֒לוּ אֶתֿ־שִׁמְךָֿ
בֶּאֱמֶתֿ הָאֵ׳ יְשׁוּעָתֵֽֿנוּ וְעֶזְרָתֵֽֿנוּ סֶֽלָה׃ בָּרוּךְֿ אַתָּה ה׳ הַטּוֹבֿ שִׁמְךָֿ
וּלְךָֿ נָאֶה לְהוֹדֿוֹתֿ׃

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The issue that I've run into is that the package I'm using for RTL text (```bidi```) requires XeTeX; not using it has led to the words being typeset in reverse order. All the letters are ordered right but the words are ordered backwards. But if ```babel``` can take care of that I'll try reworking it to see if that works

Comment: `babel` supports RTL text with XeTeX and LuaTeX. With the latter you can even switch the font and the direction based on the script without explicit markup. In fact, for RTL text in XeTeX it relies on `bidi` (with LuaTeX, `babel` uses an algorithm for bidirectional text based on Unicode). See https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-hebrew.html .

Comment: Ok so I switched to luatex and ```luabidi``` (the ```babel``` didn't work for some reason) and it does work; however, I've run into a problem where none of the vowels are aligning with the letters. I've attached an example above of the complete page.

Comment: @IanJacobs Feel free to ask for help related to `babel`.